# Pip not finding most recent versions

Tags: pip

Pip is not finding the most recent versions of some Python packages available.

When I try `pip install cachetools==4.1.0`, it gives me the error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cachetools==4.1.0 (from versions: 0.0.0, 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.5.0,
>   0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 
>   3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for cachetools==4.1.0

when it is available (https://pypi.org/project/cachetools/)
What can i do to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cachetools` support Python 2.7 only up to version 3. Version 4 requires Python 3.5+